# Clearing a TextBox leaves an invisible character

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox

I'm developing a textbased RPG . If you type something into the textbox (`tUser`), the method `Input()` gets called and processes your query. If it matches a certain condition, something else, e. g. exiting the game, will happen.

```
public void Input()
{
    if (tUser.Text.ToLower() == "ende" || listening)
    {
        if (tUser.Text.ToLower() == "ende")
        {
            if (MessageBox.Show(playername + 
                ", wollt Ihr wirklich das Spiel ohne Speichern verlassen?", "Beenden", 
                MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question) == DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                Application.Exit();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            input = tUser.Text;

            if (accept == 1 && !input.Any(char.IsDigit))
            {
                tRPG.AppendText("\nBitte gebt nur eine Zahl ein!");
            }
            else
            {     
                listening = false;
            }
        }        
    }

    // Reset
    input = "";
    tUser.Clear();
}
```

Your query will be submitted if you press Enter. After the process is done, the TextBox is being cleared.
If you try the same or any other command (again), nothing's going to happen, until you delete an "invisible" character in the TextBox.
I have also tried `tUser.ClearUndo()`.

What is this character and how can I avoid it?

Comment: WPF? Windows forms?

Comment: Yes; title has been changed.

Comment: Odd. Have you tried `tUser.Text = string.Empty;`? When you set a breakpoint on the first `if` condition and examine the value of `tUser.Text`, what does the character look like (what is the actual value)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason, the textbox keeps a carriage return. Adding `e.Handled = true` to the method which calls `Input()` solves this issue.

```
private void tUser_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Enter)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
        Input();
    }
}
```

`e.Handled` prevents the enter message from being processed after this handler has finished ([source](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/forums/remove-carriage-return-character-in-a-textbox)).

Answer (score 0):

Why not just set the text to an empty string instead of using clear?

```
tUser.Text = string.Empty;
```

Answer (score 0):

Well I believe it has something to do with the fact that your key events still set the value of the textbox or something alike after the textbox has been cleared. Anyway, a quick fix is to just use tUser.trimStart(' ') or something alike.